# user interaction with django

Tags: python, django, session, django-channels

I'm working on a question and answer system with django. my problem : I want the app to get a question from an ontology and according the user's answer get the next question. how can I have all the questions and user's answers displayed. i'm new to django, I don't know if I can use session with unauthenticated user and if I need to use websocket with the django channels library.

Comment: i guess you want to implement a form wizard system (quiz system) if so have a look at `django-formtools` https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and this a tuto that may help you getting the idea https://swapps.com/blog/how-to-do-a-wizard-form/

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to work with anonymous users the simplest way to go is to add a hidden field on the page and use it to track the user progress. The field can contain virtual session id that will point at a model record in the backend, or the entire Q/A session(ugly but fast and easy). Using REST or sockets would require similar approach.

I can't tell from the top of my mind if you can step on top of the built in session system. It will work for registered users, but I do believe that for anonymous users it gets reset on refresh(may be wrong here).